# Achieving mixed vertical layout by using LazyVGrid in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I recently started to learn SwiftUI and wanted to experiment with mixed vertical layout in SwiftUI. But cannot find anywhere how I can implement my idea:

Having 2 columns grid but in some rows to put a single element instead of 2.

Let's say I have an array of objects:

```
struct MyObj {
    isWide: Bool
}
```

and according to that `isWide` property to place 1 element in a row or 2.

I was trying something like this:

```
GeometryReader { proxy in
            LazyVGrid(columns: [
                GridItem(.fixed((proxy.size.width / 2) - 32))
            ], spacing: 16) {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.brown)
                    .frame(width: proxy.size.width - 32, height: 100)

                LazyVGrid(columns: [
                    GridItem(.fixed((proxy.size.width / 2) - 16)),
                    GridItem(.fixed((proxy.size.width / 2) - 16))
                ], spacing: 16) {
                    ForEach((0...10), id: \.self) { num in
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.brown)
                            .frame(height: 100)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But this is not giving me the flexibility what I'm looking for.
Any idea how can I achieve that?

[image]